# Millennial Media PHP Setup ( Code Integration )

Tags: php, wordpress, millennial-media

I know this going to be very easy question for people with good PHP knowledge.

I have a WordPress website self hosted. I designed it for mobile devices and I would like to install Millennial Media advertisements in it. Millennial Media does not really provide detailed instructions and web resources strangely are not available!

I have knowledge in HTML,CSS and JavaScript but very poor in PHP :( .
any way I can do some changes PHP to achieve what I want, but I can't write them from zero and integrate them by my self.

Ok long story short 
This the code provided by Millennial Media:

```
<?php 
/*--------------------------------------------------------------*/ 
/* Millennial Media PHP Ad Coding, v.7.4.20                     */ 
/* Copyright Millennial Media, Inc. 2006                        */ 
/*                                                              */ 
/* The following code requires PHP >= 4.3.0 and                 */ 
/* allow_url_fopen 1 set in php.ini file.                       */ 
/*                                                              */ 
/* NOTE:                                                        */ 
/* It is recommended that you lower the default_socket_timeout  */ 
/* value in the php.ini file to 5 seconds.                      */ 
/* This will prevent network connectivity from affecting        */ 
/* page loading.                                                */ 
/*--------------------------------------------------------------*/ 

/*------- Publisher Specific Section -------*/ 
$mm_placementid = 123456; 
$mm_adserver = "ads.mp.mydas.mobi"; 

/* The default response will be echo'd on the page     */
/* if no Ad is returned, so any valid WML/XHTML string */
/* is acceptable.                                      */
$mm_default_response = "";

/*------------------------------------------*/

/*----------- BEGIN AD INITIALIZATION ----------*/
/*----- PLEASE DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE -----*/
$mm_id = "NONE";
$mm_ua = "NONE";
@$mm_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] )){
     $mm_ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
}

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_UP_SUBNO'])) {
          $mm_id = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_UP_SUBNO'];
} elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_XID'])) {
          $mm_id = $_SERVER['HTTP_XID'];
} elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENTID'])) {
          $mm_id = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENTID'];
} else {
          $mm_id = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

$mm_url = "http://$mm_adserver/getAd.php5?apid=$mm_placementid&auid="
          . urlencode($mm_id) . "&uip=" . urlencode($mm_ip) . "&ua="
          . urlencode($mm_ua);
/*------------ END AD INITIALIZATION -----------*/
?>

<?php
/* Place this code block where you want the ad to appear */
/*------- Reusable Ad Call -------*/
@$mm_response = file_get_contents($mm_url);
echo $mm_response != FALSE ? $mm_response : $mm_default_response;
/*--------- End Ad Call ----------*/
?>
```

I want the Advertisement to appear in the footer area ( I will edit the footer.php in twenty eleven theme )
but I want to know where shall I put these pieces of codes in wordpress files or shall I create a new ones and what to name them?

would some please help me with this issue and provide me with the file's names that required to be edited and how would they look like in the end ?

Thanks

Comment: If your question boils down to "I have this script that I need integrated into my Wordpress site" then it doesn't really qualify as a programming question. Maybe http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @MikeB, it doesn't qualify as a WP question either, this one is a *Hot Potato* kind of Q and it was [multi-posted](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/83070/12615) over there too. :::: It's about a company that "`does not really provide detailed instructions and web resources strangely are not available!`"...

Comment: @brasofilo Apparently it does since a [mod answered it](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/83084)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anywhere in your page, where you want the ad to appear, let's say inside a `<div>`, use:

```
<div>
   <?php include('thatfiletheysentyou.php'); ?>
</div>
```

This will make output of that file appear where `include` is.

**EDIT: Complete rewrite:**

This is content of footer.php. I just installed wordpress for you, took 3 minutes. I edited footer.php including `<?php include('ads.php'); ?>` (see below), which appeared in footer, as expected

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the footer.
 *
 * Contains the closing of the id=main div and all content after
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Eleven
 * @since Twenty Eleven 1.0
 */
?>

    </div><!-- #main -->


    <footer id="colophon" role="contentinfo">

            <?php
                /* A sidebar in the footer? Yep. You can can customize
                 * your footer with three columns of widgets.
                 */
                if ( ! is_404() )
                    get_sidebar( 'footer' );
        ?>

        <div id="site-generator">
        <div>
         <?php include('ads.php'); ?>
        </div>
    <?php do_action( 'twentyeleven_credits' ); ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( __( 'http://wordpress.org/', 'twentyeleven' ) ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Semantic Personal Publishing Platform', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>"><?php printf( __( 'Proudly powered by %s', 'twentyeleven' ), 'WordPress' ); ?></a>
        </div>
</footer><!-- #colophon -->
</div><!-- #page -->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Now if you got a file from the ad company, change `ads.php` above to this file name. If you got a code pasted in (i don't know, an e-mail, website) - create a file `ads.php` and paste whatever you got from them. Place that file in `twentyeleven` subfolder. My file looks like this:

```
<?php
  echo 'HEHEHE!';
  //instead of this just paste your code here
?>
```

and on the page it is like so:
[1 http://www.spzozwolsztyn.internetdsl.pl/wpress.jpg](http://www.spzozwolsztyn.internetdsl.pl/wpress.jpg)

If you got tired of them remove include line from footer.php.

Comment: It was noted in the duplicate on WPSE that @lotav does not like this answer. Clearly if the code they sent you wasn't in a file but just a random snippet, then maybe it could just be put in a file? Creating a text file and copy pasting is trivial

Comment: Clearly OP doesn't like the other one too. But having 1-line php.ini is sort of a problem in and of itself...

Comment: dear @Kitet I've done pasting the code in the footer and the other way you have typed , both of them game me the same result. The result was a text of two links. " http://bank20.mi.clicks.mp.mydas.mobi/handleClick.php5?apid=111065&auid=85.96.53.53&uip=85.96.53.53&mmid=5344&osid=20&urid=vBv18R1Hu5PlEWHCb_C1WWWC&ri=20&acid=465425&mtpid=0http://images.millennialmedia.com/24144/465425.gifimage/gif90728 " .. and about the PHP.INI , the one I have on godaddy server is php5.ini and it has only cgi.fix_pathinfo=1 ..

Comment: I checked phpinfo for the web site to find out about the allow_url_fopen .. it says .. allow_url_fopen On ( for both the local value and master value ) doesn't that serve the same requirement as 1 or it has to be changed ?